# Determining if a random variable follows a Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose we take some data about persons entering a particular store over some length of time $[0, t]$ hours. If we want to see if this data follows a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$, we can conduct a $\chi ^2$-test.

In my notes it says it is wrong, as a quick indication, to check if the mean and variance of the sample data are the same. Why is this? Surely if the mean and variance of the data aren't at all close, then there is no chance that the sample data would've likely come from a Poisson distribution.

Comment: On the other hand, mean being equal to variance is not sufficient to conclude that the data is Poisson.

Comment: And that's it. $ $